# do I need to rebuild my lucene index for this change?

Tags: lucene, solr

Do I need to rebuild a Lucene index when I only add a random field to a schema?  Or could I run some code to update that field without rebuilding the index?

This is the field I need to add: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html

In this case, Lucene is running on Solr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC you don't need to rebuild the index or run any code to update a random field, since that field type doesn't really have a value, i.e. its value is generated on demand depending on the full field name.

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be the case.  My Lucene book is still in the mail.  :)